# Verifying Signature from a block_io python notification json object

Tags: python, json, encoding, decoding, verification

I'm using `block_io` in python to send notifications on transaction updates. This comes in a json format like this:

```json
{
    "event_id": "...",
    "notification_id": "...",
    "delivery_attempt": 1,
    "type": "...",
    "data": "...",
    "created_at": 1426104819,
    "signature" : "..."
}
```

The details of the keys of the above json are below:

- `event_id` : event ID for debugging purposes
- `notification_id` : a unique identifier issued when you created the notification
- `delivery_attempt` : number of times we've tried delivering this event
- `type` : the type of notification, helps you understand the data sent below
- `data` : the notification data
- `created_at` : timestamp of when we created this notification
- `signature` :  signed hash of this data (excluding the signature key)

I'm just wondering how I can generate the signature myself from the incoming data to verify it against the incoming data (obviously using my secret key I imagine). How do I make sure that the notification is indeed from `block_io` and not from someone else.

trying

```py
json.dumps(json_obj) into hmac.new(secret.encode(), incoming.encode(),
hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

but still did not get a matching signature